# dbms_xmldom - creating an xml from an oracle database

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, plsql

I am trying to create an xml file from an oracle database.

I am not able to get the correct format and was wondering if I could get some assistance.

This is part of the script:

```
l_record_element := dbms_xmldom.createElement(l_domdoc, 'record_type');
dbms_xmldom.setAttribute(l_record_element,'desc', r_dept.public1);
l_record_node := dbms_xmldom.appendChild(l_dept_node,dbms_xmldom.makeNode(l_record_element));
```

my output:

```
<record_type desc="Public"/>
```

The output I need:

```
<record_type desc="Public">PUBLIC</record_type>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create and append a text node with the `PUBIC` value.

Demo showing that coming from the same cursor that provides the record type:

```
set serveroutput on

declare
  l_domdoc dbms_xmldom.domdocument;
  l_dept_node dbms_xmldom.domnode;
  l_record_node dbms_xmldom.domnode;
  l_record_element dbms_xmldom.domelement;
  l_record_text dbms_xmldom.domtext;
  l_tmp_node dbms_xmldom.domnode;
  l_xmltype xmltype;
  l_buffer varchar2(32767);
begin
  l_domdoc := dbms_xmldom.newDOMDocument; --(xmltype('<data />'));

  for r_dept in (select 'Public' as public1, 'PUBLIC' as public2 from dual) loop
    l_dept_node := dbms_xmldom.makeNode(l_domdoc);

    -- code you showed
    l_record_element := dbms_xmldom.createElement(l_domdoc, 'record_type');
    dbms_xmldom.setAttribute(l_record_element,'desc', r_dept.public1);
    l_record_node := dbms_xmldom.appendChild(l_dept_node, dbms_xmldom.makeNode(l_record_element));
    -- add a text node
    l_record_text := dbms_xmldom.createTextNode(l_domdoc, r_dept.public2);
    l_tmp_node := dbms_xmldom.appendChild(l_record_node, dbms_xmldom.makeNode(l_record_text));

    -- display the node for demo
    l_xmltype := dbms_xmldom.getXmlType(l_domdoc);
    dbms_xmldom.freeDocument(l_domdoc);
    dbms_output.put_line(l_xmltype.getClobVal);
  end loop;
end;
/

<record_type desc="Public">PUBLIC</record_type>

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```